# Why a propagating pulse has no DC spectral component?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, waves

I found in a text that : **"*Because the laser pulse represents a propagating electromagnetic wave packet,
the dc component of its spectrum vanishes. Hence the time integral over the
electric field is zero.*"**

Why is it so? I mostly don't understand why should a pulse not have any DC component.

Comment: Consider expanding out the electric field as a harmonic (fourier) series expansion, the first, constant, term should vanish for a pulse as stated below, and the other terms will be integrated over full wavelengths and hence vanish regardless their Fourier coefficients (I.e shape of the pulse)

Comment: Or, more in line with the question one could hold a point fixed and integrate it the field over time as the harmonics passed, either way it should be zero

Comment: @R.Rankin, the fact that $E(t)$ is a 'windowed' cosine doesn't guarantee that there is zero DC component.  For example, consider the 'pulse' $[u(t+\pi /2) - u(t - \pi /2)]\cos(t)$ which *clearly* has a non-zero DC component.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri  if [u(t+π/2)−u(t−π/2)]cos(t) doesn't go towards zero as t goes to plus or minus infinity then that surely can't be considered a 'pulse'. If it does, then the DC component must vanish as stated below in user157879's answer

Comment: @R.Rankin, the function I gave above is zero for $t < -\pi /2, t > \pi /2$ and equal to $\cos(t)$ otherwise.  The integral over all time is $2$

Comment: @Alfred Centauri, the pulse you have described is not localized in space, you need to enforce the dispersion relation of light here.  You are right that not all pulses of an arbitrary field average to zero like your textbook says.  However,  light has a very special dispersion relation in free space. Other types of waves (longitudinal plasma oscillations for example) may circumvent the textbook's statement by having a different dispersion relation.

Comment: Apologies, I should have made my initial comment more clear, I was simply assuming pulses of electric fields which satisfy the accompanying laws (as the question states) not any general pulse

Comment: @R.Rankin, I invite you to take a look at the pdf I linked to in my comment to the answer by user157879 which is, I suspect, the text that the quote in the OP's post is from.  Consider the integral with respect to time that the author asserts is zero and yet, by inspection, it doesn't seem likely that it is.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri another way to consider this is that if you perform a multipole expansion upon an electromagnetic radiation field, the first (monopole) term must vanish, corresponding to the well-known physical result that there exists no monopole radiation (which if it did exist, would then correspond to a non-zero DC component of the radiation field).

Comment: @R.Rankin, it's not that I disagree with the statement that a propagating electromagnetic pulse has no DC component (as I mentioned in my comment to the answer), it's that the integral over all time in the referenced pdf doesn't obviously yield zero.  Am I missing something that you haven't yet mentioned?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri  I just don't think it was explained very well,  I think they were just saying that the integral over all time of the electric field is equal to the DC component of the Fourier transform by virtue of 1=e^(ikt) for k=0. Ie, they rewrite the integral as the Fourier transform of the electric field component with zero frequency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pulse having a DC component would imply that there is a constant electric field forever after and before the pulse arrives. Because light obeys a dispersion relation $\omega = c  k$, a field with $\omega=0$ does not propagate. Hence, the DC component is spatially and temporally uniform. In that case,  it is meaningless to attribute the DC component to the laser pulse because it will be there far after the pulse leaves and before it even arrives.

Edit: OP sounds like he is still confused. The essential point here is that if the pulse satisfies the following:
$$\lim_{t \to \pm \infty}\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x},t)=0$$
$$\lim_{\mathbf{x} \to \pm \infty}\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x},t)=0$$

Then there is no DC component. The proof is that at $t\to\pm\infty$ and $\mathbf{x}\to\pm\infty$ any DC component will no go to zero strictly speaking.

Provided $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x},t)$ satisfies these conditions (as the usual definition of a pulse should) then if you integrate $\mathbf{E}$ over all time, you average to zero.

Comment: While I agree, I'm a bit confused by the text from which the quote is taken (which I looked up and found [here](http://booksite.elsevier.com/samplechapters/9780122154935/Sample_Chapters/02~Chapter_1.pdf)),  it doesn't seem obvious that the integral vanishes.  Of course it's late and I'm tired and I'm probably missing something elementary.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri see above comments

Comment: @user157879 can you specify a bit more about the dispersion relation. I understand that a propagating wave has a form like $f(x-\omega t)$. So $\omega=0$ would not be a propagating wave. But how is that any related to dispersion relation?

Comment: @Icchyamoy for light waves in vacuum, all modes propagate at fixed speed $c$ (i.e. the speed of light). This fixes the relation between the spatial variations and time dependence of the wave. If $\omega=0$, then $k=0$, and the wave is isotropic in space. This does not need to be the case for all waves! Consider the dispersion relation $\omega^2+\omega_0^2=c^2k^2$. In such a case, even if $\omega=0$, $k$ is nonzero and the wave will vary spatially. It is even possible that the wave is localized in space but has no time-dependence! This cannot happen for light in vacuum because it moves at $c$.